# Cannot process cube using SQL agent job in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, ssas

I have an issue where we have a user who has used his own AD account to create and deploy the cube back when he was the sole DBA.

I would like to have an proxy account with a password known internally instead of his own credentials.

For this I have created a new AD account, `ProcessCube`, which I have given `sysadmin` rights on the underlying `SQL Engine`. I have also created a role called `Process cube` on the `SSAS database` with `read and write` rights on every cube and `read` rights on `data sources`.

In SSAS I have double clicked the `data sources` and under `Impersonation mode` I have replaced the old credentials with the credentials of the newly created AD account `ProcessCube`.

**I have not deployed the cube with the new credentials, but rather let the SQL SSAS command in the SQL agent do the trick, do I need to deploy the cube first?**

In the SQL Agent I've made `ProcessCube` the Owner of the job which is a `SQL Server Analysis Server Command`.

When I try to execute the SQL agent job I get the error:

```
The following system error occurred:  The user name or password is incorrect.  Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Service
```

I assume I need some more credentials, what more do I need? What have  I missed?

The command I try to execute in the agent is as follows:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <ErrorConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
    <KeyErrorLimit>-1</KeyErrorLimit>
    <KeyNotFound>IgnoreError</KeyNotFound>
    <NullKeyNotAllowed>IgnoreError</NullKeyNotAllowed>
  </ErrorConfiguration>
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>DataBaseID</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work now.

In Management Studios I extended `Databases->theDatabase->Data source` and from there I had the option `ImpersonateInfo` with the value `ImpersonateAccount`.

I clicked at `ImpersonateAccount` and then on `...`. From there I entered the credentials of the newly created account, and *voilá*.